# Numbered pagination pages Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I display child pages of a specific pages like this :

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'page',
'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'order'          => 'ASC',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'child_of' => $post->ID
);

$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) { ?>

<?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="bloc-page">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What I want is a numbered navigation, only three posts each pages. But I don't know how to do that and I tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked.

Thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after the end of your `while` loop add following lines:

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $parent->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

For further help please read official wordpress pagination documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of solutions did you do? Did you try wp_reset_postdata();?